# Responsive Iframe height cross-domain without having control of source page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm developing a responsive website that will have some iframes, in the iframes I'll load content from other domain which I can't edit it.

So, it is possible somehow, to get the content height? From another domain and without access to source page.

Comment: I don't think that would be possible, you can only have contents height of iframe only when both pages are on same domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access any content inside an `iframe` when loading a page from another domain.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do cross domain AJAX requests with [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) or [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) but then you need to have access to the embedded websites. Possibly you could try [YQL](http://christianheilmann.com/2009/08/25/tutorial-scraping-and-turning-a-web-site-into-a-widget-with-yql/) to get the content. Mirroring on your own server would do the job. Otherwise you will hit [SOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).